# Run method from time to time and cancel in asyntask method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to run an action every 5 minutes, but in a particular part I need to run another action to cancel and when finished, resuming action. Is there any way to do this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_evento);
    cronTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CronPush.class));
         }
    };
    cron = new Timer();
    cron.schedule(cronTimerTask, 0, 30000);
}

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        cron.cancel();
        Sincronizacion s = new Sincronizacion();
        s.sincronizarBD(MenuEvento.this, codigoEvento);
        resume();
        return null;
    }

public void resume() {
    cron = new Timer();
    cron.schedule(cronTimerTask, 0, 30000);
}
```

Comment: I tried to take a Timer and TimeStack, also cancel and restart an instance of it, but can not get it to work.

Comment: ready! my code in my post

Comment: There are not 5 minutes, since I'm only testing